# ZeroMQ REP/REQ doesn't work between public IP and IP behind the NAT

Tags: tcp, request, zeromq, reply

I want to run the zmq REP/REQ HelloWrold example using two different machine. 
The source code is here: 
CLIENT: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient
SERVER: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwserver

I run the server on a cloud machine with a public IP address and the client on my laptop that is behind a NAT. I have verified that the address are reachable (pinging the IP) and the ports are opened (using netcat).

So the client sends the message, the server receive it and sends back a reply message using the same socket but the client doesn't receive it.

If I run this example locally or between two cloud machine located in different geografic areas (with public ip) it works.

Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that there is a problem on ubuntu (quantal) ppa of libzmq.
Using libzmq-3.2.2 taken from the website it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely due to incompatible versions (there were some alpha/beta releases with incompatible protocols). It's a FAQ question, see http://www.zeromq.org/area:faq#toc6

Comment: I've tried the client/server hellowold example compiled with the same version (3.2.2). Using the version of this ppa https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/zeromq it doesn't work, while using the version downloaded from the website it works.